# Apache Beam local Python dependencies

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have local Python package which I want to use inside of the Apache Beam pipeline with DataFlow Runner.
I tried to follow instructions provided in the documentation: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/ (section *Local or non-PyPI Dependencies*) but without success.

My package has the following structure:

```
my_common
├── __init__.py
└── shared
    ├── __init__.py
    └── something.py
```

With `something.py` file containing:

```
def hello_world():
    return "Hello"
```

Package was build using `python setup.py sdist` command.

Now, I have Apache Beam pipeline configured as follows:

```
pipeline_parameters = [
    '--project', project_id,
    '--staging_location', staging_location,
    '--temp_location', temp_location,
    '--max_num_workers', 1,
    "--extra_package", "/absolute/path/to/my/package/my_common-1.0.tar.gz"
]


p = beam.Pipeline("DataFlowRunner", argv=pipeline_parameters)
# rest of the pipeline definition
```

One of the pipeline map functions has the following code, which uses my module:

```
from my_common.shared import something
logging.info(something.hello_world())
```

Every time when I schedule this pipeline to DataFlow, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named shared
```

Interesting part is that when I install this package (from .tar.gz) file on another environment, I can import and run function from it without any problems. It seems to me that DataFlow does not install the package before running the pipeline.

**What is the proper way of managing and deploying local Python dependencies to Google DataFlow?**

*//update:*
The solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605344/1955346 is not sufficient for my use case, since I need to have my local packages in completely different folder and `setup.py` for my pipeline already has some contents (I cannot use setup.py of external package as suggested there).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of providing it through `extra-packages` provide it using `setup_file`

Use `setuptools` to define your `setup_file`, it will look somewhat as follows

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="dataflow_pipeline_dependencies",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Marcin Zablocki",
    author_email="youemail@domain.com",
    description=("Custom python utils needed for dataflow cloud runner"),
    packages=[
        'my_common'
        ]
)
```

and pass it using `--setup_file` parameter as follows

```
pipeline_parameters = [
    '--project', project_id,
    '--staging_location', staging_location,
    '--temp_location', temp_location,
    '--max_num_workers', 1,
    "--setup_file", "/absolute/path/to/your/package/my_common"
]


p = beam.Pipeline("DataFlowRunner", argv=pipeline_parameters)
# rest of the pipeline definition
```

where `/absolute/path/to/your/package/my_common` is **path to the directory where the package is stored**

Comment: The problem is that I've already have ```setup.py``` with some custom commands defined for my pipeline. Is there any other way? What is the purpose of ```extra_packages``` then?

Comment: I have been experimenting with beam for a month now, even i tried using the `extra-packages` parameter first, but even i had not luck with it. The documentation is not clear enough about how it works.

Comment: Also It is completely ok to have custom commands along with providing the `packages` in the setup file. I dont see any reason, it would affect the custom commands

Comment: But my setup file is in the directory where I have my pipeline, it already uses ```packages=setuptools.find_packages()``` in ```setup()```. Adding ```["my_common"]``` does not work.

Comment: Since its an array, you could just append the package? Make sure the package folder is in the same folder as the setup file

Comment: That is the problem, my package is in another folder, I cannot copy-paste it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156098/discussion-between-marcin-zablocki-and-anuj).