# How do I get a dataframe or database write from TFX BulkInferrer?

Tags: database, tensorflow, output, tfx

I'm very new to TFX, but have an apparently-working ML Pipeline which is to be used via [BulkInferrer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/api_docs/python/tfx/components/BulkInferrer). That seems to produce output exclusively in Protobuf format, but since I'm running bulk inference I want to pipe the results to a database instead. (DB output seems like it should be the default for bulk inference, since both Bulk Inference & DB access take advantage of parallelization... but Protobuf is a per-record, serialized format.)

I assume I could use something like [Parquet-Avro-Protobuf](https://github.com/rdblue/parquet-avro-protobuf/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/ProtobufToParquet.java) to do the conversion (though that's in Java and the rest of the pipeline's in Python), or I could write something myself to consume all the protobuf messages one-by-one, convert them into JSON, deserialize the JSON into a list of dicts, and load the dict into a Pandas DataFrame, or store it as a bunch of key-value pairs which I treat like a single-use DB... but that sounds like a lot of work and pain involving parallelization and optimization for a very common use case. The top-level Protobuf message definition is Tensorflow's [PredictionLog](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/prediction_log.proto).

This *must* be a common use case, because TensorFlowModelAnalytics functions like [this one](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/analyze_raw_data?hl=en) consume Pandas DataFrames. I'd rather be able to write directly to a DB (preferably Google BigQuery), or a Parquet file (since Parquet / Spark seems to parallelize better than Pandas), and again, those seem like they should be common use cases, but I haven't found any examples.  Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms?

I also looked at the [PredictExtractor](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tfx/model_analysis/api_docs/python/tfma/extractors/PredictExtractor?hl=en), since "extracting predictions" sounds close to what I want... but the official documentation appears silent on how that class is supposed to be used. I thought [TFTransformOutput](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/TFTransformOutput?hl=en) sounded like a promising verb, but instead it's a noun.

I'm clearly missing something fundamental here. Is there a reason no one wants to store BulkInferrer results in a database? Is there a configuration option that allows me to write the results to a DB? Maybe I want to add a [ParquetIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.26.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html) or [BigQueryIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.26.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html) instance to the TFX pipeline? (TFX docs say it uses Beam "[under the hood](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/transform)" but that doesn't say much about how I should use them together.) But the syntax in those documents looks sufficiently different from my TFX code that I'm not sure if they're compatible?

Help?

Comment: Closely-related discussion on TFX's GitHub forum: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/2478

Comment: Part of the issue we've faced with this and other custom components is deployment to Dataflow. There's an issue related to that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604870/apache-beam-local-python-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Copied from the related issue for greater visibility)

After some digging, here is an alternative approach, which assumes no knowledge of the `feature_spec` before-hand.  Do the following:

- Set the `BulkInferrer` to write to `output_examples` rather than `inference_result` by adding a [output_example_spec](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/3aeb6d1b19f1b6a8090f8cda22b45bb81aafdd1a/tfx/proto/bulk_inferrer.proto#L43) to the component construction.
- Add a  `StatisticsGen` and a `SchemaGen` component in the main pipeline right after the `BulkInferrer` to generate a schema for the aforementioned `output_examples`
- Use the artifacts from `SchemaGen` and `BulkInferrer` to read the TFRecords and do whatever is neccessary.

```py
bulk_inferrer = BulkInferrer(
     ....
     output_example_spec=bulk_inferrer_pb2.OutputExampleSpec(
         output_columns_spec=[bulk_inferrer_pb2.OutputColumnsSpec(
             predict_output=bulk_inferrer_pb2.PredictOutput(
                 output_columns=[bulk_inferrer_pb2.PredictOutputCol(
                     output_key='original_label_name',
                     output_column='output_label_column_name', )]))]
     ))

 statistics = StatisticsGen(
     examples=bulk_inferrer.outputs.output_examples
 )

 schema = SchemaGen(
     statistics=statistics.outputs.output,
 )
```

After that, one can do the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tfx.utils import io_utils
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import schema_utils

# read schema from SchemaGen
schema_path = '/path/to/schemagen/schema.pbtxt'
schema_proto = io_utils.SchemaReader().read(schema_path)
spec = schema_utils.schema_as_feature_spec(schema_proto).feature_spec

# read inferred results
data_files = ['/path/to/bulkinferrer/output_examples/examples/examples-00000-of-00001.gz']
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(data_files, compression_type='GZIP')

# parse dataset with spec
def parse(raw_record):
    return tf.io.parse_example(raw_record, spec)

dataset = dataset.map(parse)
```

At this point, the dataset is like any other parsed dataset, so its trivial to write a CSV, or to a BigQuery table or whatever from there. It certainly helped us in [ZenML](https://github.com/maiot-io/zenml/t) with our [BatchInferencePipeline](https://github.com/maiot-io/zenml/blob/newpipelines/zenml/core/pipelines/infer_pipeline.py#L150).

Comment: Upvoting because the approach makes sense, is well documented, and looks like it will work. I'll hold off on accepting it until I can verify this works.

Comment: @Hamza Tahir: Could you give more explanation on `output_key` and `output_column`? The document says they are "Key in signature output" and "Output column name", but I still don't understand their meanings (https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/3aeb6d1b19f1b6a8090f8cda22b45bb81aafdd1a/tfx/proto/bulk_inferrer.proto#L79)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here to document what we did, even though I think @Hamza Tahir's answer below is objectively better. This may provide an option for other situations where it's necessary to change the operation of an out-of-the-box TFX component. It's hacky though:

We copied and edited the file tfx/components/bulk_inferrer/executor.py, replacing this transform in the `_run_model_inference()` method's internal pipeline:

```
| 'WritePredictionLogs' >> beam.io.WriteToTFRecord(
             os.path.join(inference_result.uri, _PREDICTION_LOGS_FILE_NAME),
             file_name_suffix='.gz',
             coder=beam.coders.ProtoCoder(prediction_log_pb2.PredictionLog)))
```

with this one:

```
| 'WritePredictionLogsBigquery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
           'our_project:namespace.TableName',
           schema='SCHEMA_AUTODETECT',
           write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
           create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
           custom_gcs_temp_location='gs://our-storage-bucket/tmp',
           temp_file_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
           ignore_insert_ids=True,
       )
```

(This works because when you import the BulkInferrer component, the per-node work gets farmed out to these executors running on the worker nodes, and TFX copies its own library onto those nodes. It doesn't copy *everything* from user-space libaries, though, which is why we couldn't just subclass BulkInferrer and import our custom version.)

We had to make sure the table at `'our_project:namespace.TableName'` had a schema compatible with the model's output, but didn't have to translate that schema into JSON / AVRO.

In theory, my group would like to make a pull request with TFX built around this, but for now we're hard-coding a couple key parameters, and don't have the time to get this to a real public / production state.

Comment: Hey @Sarah Messer, check out ZenML (https://github.com/maiot-io/zenml) - From your requirements, it might be useful. Feel free to reach out directly as well - we're looking for use-cases to work with as its in the early stages of development

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to this party but this is some code I use for this task:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_log_pb2
import pandas as pd


def parse_prediction_logs(inference_filenames: List[Text]): -> pd.DataFrame
    """
    Args:
        inference files:  tf.io.gfile.glob(Inferrer artifact uri)
    Returns:
        a dataframe of userids, predictions, and features
    """

    def parse_log(pbuf):
        # parse the protobuf
        message = prediction_log_pb2.PredictionLog()
        message.ParseFromString(pbuf)
        # my model produces scores and classes and I extract the topK classes
        predictions = [x.decode() for x in (message
                                            .predict_log
                                            .response
                                            .outputs['output_2']
                                            .string_val
                                            )[:10]]
        # here I parse the input tf.train.Example proto
        inputs = tf.train.Example()
        inputs.ParseFromString(message
                               .predict_log
                               .request
                               .inputs['input_1'].string_val[0]
                               )

        # you can pull out individual features like this         
        uid = inputs.features.feature["userId"].bytes_list.value[0].decode()

        feature1 = [
            x.decode() for x in inputs.features.feature["feature1"].bytes_list.value
        ]

        feature2 = [
            x.decode() for x in inputs.features.feature["feature2"].bytes_list.value
        ]

        return (uid, predictions, feature1, feature2)

    return pd.DataFrame(
        [parse_log(x) for x in
         tf.data.TFRecordDataset(inference_filenames, compression_type="GZIP").as_numpy_iterator()
        ], columns = ["userId", "predictions", "feature1", "feature2"]
    )
```