# TFX Pushed model working fine when used in BQML, but error when using with BulkInferrer

Tags: inference, tfx

Followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/65979056/12559246 to get the o/p of BulkInferrer to a dataframe. Still error persists in BulkInferrer module.

Code Snippet:-
[BQExampleGen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo6Fx.png)
[BulkInferrer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxsK8.png)

The model created by pusher in same pipeline is able to perform inference successfully when used in BQML with exact same query as used in above BQExampleGen.

But when using BulkInferrer along with Pusher, error is encountered in BulkInferrer component:-
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ddzr.png)

Please let me know for any more details. Any Help ?